# How can you pass each element in an array to an object constructor using implode?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, constructor

Given a simple class:

```
class Foo {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Attempting to instantiate the class by imploding an array of values fails:

```
$params = array(2,'TestFoo2');
$baz = new Foo(implode(",", $params)); // doesn't work
```

The entire imploded array string is passed into the first field, id, and name is set to NULL.  What is the correct syntax to send the values of an array as parameters to an object constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a regular function call you'd use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array), for instantiating a class you'll have to use [reflection](http://www.php.net/reflectionclass):

```
$baz = (new ReflectionClass('Foo'))->newInstanceArgs($params);
```

In PHP 5.6+ you can use [variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), a.k.a. unpacking:

```
$baz = new Foo(...$params);
```

Comment: Variable-length argument lists works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing the constructor wrong number of parameters. Implode returns a single string value, which is the concatenation of elements in array.

Should be something like:

```
 $baz = new Foo($params[0], $params[1]);
```

Comment: Yes, it's like as I said ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's working good, but no as you expected. Maybe you need to receive as an array

```
public function __construct($array)
{
    $this->id = $array['id'] ;
    $this->name = $array['name'] ;
}
$params = array("id"=>2, "name" =>'TestFoo2');
$baz = new Foo( $params);
```

Comment: Why downvote? I answered correctly to OP question. `What is the correct syntax to send the values of an array as parameters to an object constructor?`

Comment: I did not DV, but I asked how to send the values of the array.  Your solution is sending the actual array.

Comment: You can't make by the way you attempt to do. There's a solution with `eval` but you must not use it because security reasons. If you got an array of arguments, you need to pass them manually `new Foo($array[0], $array[1])`

Comment: Ok, I didn't know this. Good solution